# ocaml: why does specific type mismatch 'a signature

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner and I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong. All guidance is appreciated. I have the signature

```
val input :
           arpv4:('a -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ipv4:('a -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ipv6:('a -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ?decode:(Mirage_protocols.Ethernet.proto ->
                   Cstruct.t -> Mirage_protocols.Ethernet.proto * 'a) ->
           t -> Cstruct.t -> unit Lwt.t
```

The goal is to be generic and defer implementation to the parameter functions. If I implement expressions using the type `Cstruct.t`, such as,

```
...
   decode:(fun proto payload -> (proto, payload))
```

I get the error

```
     Values do not match:
         val input :
           arpv4:(Cstruct.t -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ipv4:(Cstruct.t -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ipv6:(Cstruct.t -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ?decode:(Mirage_protocols.Ethernet.proto ->
                   Cstruct.t -> Mirage_protocols.Ethernet.proto * Cstruct.t) ->
           t -> Cstruct.t -> unit Lwt.t
       is not included in
         val input :
           arpv4:('a -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ipv4:('a -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ipv6:('a -> unit Lwt.t) ->
           ?decode:(Mirage_protocols.Ethernet.proto ->
                   Cstruct.t -> Mirage_protocols.Ethernet.proto * 'a) ->
           t -> Cstruct.t -> unit Lwt.t
```

I don't understand why `Cstruct.t` mismatches `'a`. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the same question was asked in https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/why-doesnt-a-specific-type-fulfill-a/5525 , please cross-link if asking the same question twice to avoid duplicating work.

Answer (score 0):

When `'a` appears on the left side of an arrow it means the function accepts any type. I.e., the function has to be polymorphic. It doesn't mean that the function can accept any single type, it means that the function must accept all possible types.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, in ocaml a type variable 'a, 'b and so forth stands for "for all types, as inferred by the compiler".  The simplest case is the identity function (one which just returns its argument), which can take and return any type, and whose argument and return type can therefore be denoted by type variable 'a.  Or, a list or array can hold any type, so functions returning lists or arrays may have type 'a list or 'a array.

But many problems cannot be solved "for all types", namely where the code written is specific to a particular type or particular types.  As mentioned, an identity function can take and return any type.  But for example a function which multiplies its argument by 2 and returns the product must take and return a number, either an int or a float.  Added to this, in ocaml there are separate operators for multiplying ints and floats: so if you want to have a function which works with both ints and floats you might want to use a number variant and match on that, in which case you wouldn't need to rely on module level polymorphism - the code would be monomorphic on the variant type.

But in a case of that kind you might not want to have a function taking and/or returning a variant.  You might want to provide separate implementations for ints and floats and call up the appropriate version explicitly.  You can do this with module interfaces and module implementations.  Functors are useful when implementing this, as a shorthand for writing out specialized modules by hand.

You have asked the same question at https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/why-doesnt-a-specific-type-fulfill-a/5525/6 .  There you have been provided with an example of polymorphism of this kind at the module level using sharing constraint:

```
module type Printable = sig
  type t
  val say : t -> unit
end

module Int_print: Printable with type t := int = struct
  let say i = Printf.printf "%d\n" i
end

module String_print: Printable with type t := string = struct
  let say s = Printf.printf "%s\n" s
end

let () =
  let open Int_print in
  say 20 ;
  let open String_print in
  say "hello again"
```

Ocaml does not have 'ad hoc' polymorphism, whereby the compiler will choose which one of such user-provided alternatives should be applied in any particular case (known as 'function overloading' in C++ and similar languages): in ocaml the coder has to state this herself, as in the example above.